# access variables inside two ajax functions

Tags: jquery, ajax, scope, html

can i achieve this even more simpler way ???
Here i have my requests populated in a html table... 
My table is like

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
request number
</td>
<td align="center">
approve
</td>
<td align="center">
reject
</td>
<td align="center">
query
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As u can see i have a single row only in mt html code...But after the ajax call my table is populated with several rows of requests..

Now after this is done i have to get the count of table rows and show it in my

### pending requests()

LIKE :
pending requests(9)...where 9 is the number of pending requests.

Comment: Provide sample code and describe what have you tried.

Comment: No need to say that you are a nwebie in your question.

Comment: $.ajax function{
..
..
..}
success()...
now here i have to get my no of pending request in that <span>

$("#sancwatapproval").text(parseInt$("#sancwatapproval").text() + (parseInt(GET my pending request method result),10);
Now again for my pending request in other department i have to use this same procedure and show the total number of pending requests

Comment: or can i achieve this even more simpler way ???
Like i have my requests populated in a html table... 
My table is like 
<table>
<tr>
<td>
request number
</td>
<td align="center">
approve
</td>
<td align="center">
reject
</td>
<td align="center">
query
</td>
</tr>
</table>
As u can see i have a single row only in mt html code...But after the ajax call my table is populated with several rows of requests..

Now after this is done i have to get the count of table rows and show it in my <h2>pending requests(<span></span>)</h2>
LIKE :
pending requests(9)...where 9 is the number of pending requests.

Comment: Update your question. Don't just pour your codes on comment. Its hard to understand unformatted codes. Thanks.